# sudo pip install cryptography error: externally-managed-environment

Tags: python, pip, cryptography, pynput

```
$ sudo pip install cryptography 
error: externally-managed-environment
```

```
× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
    python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
    sure you have python3-full installed.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
    it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.
    
    See /usr/share/doc/python3.11/README.venv for more information.

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.
```

Same issue in `pip install pynput`
How can ı fix this?

Comment: The rest of the error isn't formatted properly.

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR: Use `apt install python3-cryptography` instead of `sudo pip install cryptography`.

Long story: Mixing two package managers (`apt` and `pip` here) is always a bad idea, so error message or not, please avoid `sudo pip install`.

PEP 668 is a way for distributions to explicitly tell users to avoid falling is this pit. Your distribution used it to tell you to use `apt` instead.

In fact there's three good solutions:

- Use `apt install python3-cryptography` instead. In this case there's no weird mixing of package managers: you installed `python3` using `apt`, you're installing `cryptography` using `apt`: no surprises.
- Use a venv: `python3 -m venv .venv` then `source .venv/bin/activate`, then `pip install cryptography`. In this case the installation is contained inside the `.venv` directory: no mixing of what apt does and what pip does, no surprises.
- Use a Python not provided by your distrib. I often compile many Python interpreters myself using [a short bash function](https://git.afpy.org/mdk/compile-python), those interpreters are of a different version that the system Python3 so I obviously can't use `apt install python3-...`, it would bring the wrong version of the lib. So I use either a venv either a `pip install cryptography`, `pip` will install it in `~/.local/lib/`, again no clash between `apt` and `pip`, no surprises.

Comment: Thanks. The method with ``venv`` helped me with ``pip install -r requriments.txt`` installation

Answer (score 3):

Try that it will be work am sure :

> sudo pip3 install cryptography --break-system-packages

or that

> sudo pip install cryptography --break-system-packages

i hope helps u.

Answer (score 0):

This is a result of [PEP 668](https://peps.python.org/pep-0668/). If you cannot or don't want to use the `venv` module, you can force pip to install the package with the `--break-system-packages` switch, which will override the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using pipx (*sudo apt install -y pipx*)
I am on arch using pipx (*sudo pacman -S python-pipx*),
it helped for me.
To use run **pipx install cryptography**